# jSignature canvas jquery to show in ASPX.NET

Tags: asp.net, html

I am using JSignature to capture the user's signature through html5/Jquery Mobile.
I have the signaturature which is alphanumeric values then store in the SQL Server 2008 database.

I need to show the signature in ASP.NET but now sure how to convert those alphanumberic values into something that ASP.NET can read.

```
    jSignature
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the embedded img show as:

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh .... " >`

where `base64,iVBORw0KGgoA...` is your data from the signature.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works great. Any way we can make the size say 60% of what it is.

Comment: @NatePet yes, just set width="60%" inside the image tag.

Comment: I think that you spend too much db space by using the base64 to store it on the database. You can use asp.net functions to convert the base64 to binary, and then when you won to show it you can again translate it to base64.